# Concurrent WiFi Direct groups on Android (is it possible, and what are the upper limits?)

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

My application requires sending several hundred kilobytes between random nodes on a local decentralised network (many to many) several times a second. The understanding I have of WiFi-Direct is that one device acts as server (Group Owner - GO) and all the other as client nodes. Implying to send data between random nodes requires an upload to the GO followed by a second transfer from the GO to the recipient... I am looking for a truly P2P solution that doesn't require the double handling. In the WiFi Direct specification it is explicitly stated

> This specification does not preclude a P2P Device operating as a member of more than one P2P Group simultaneously, however, such operation is out of scope and therefore not described.

My question is if would be technically feasible (efficient) with the Android implementation of WiFi Direct to initiate a dedicated group between every pair? So for 10 devices in the room each device would be a group owner waiting for any transfers addressed to it, while simultaneously holding open connections to 9 other groups for any data generated at the node and targeted for another.

Alternately could this be done by dynamically creating (how resource intensive is this?) and destroying groups as required with the process being mediated by a separate traditional server client messaging group?